# Identify and remove data points with high leverage and large residuals

Tags: r, linear-regression, outliers

I want to identify data points with high leverage and large residuals. My aim is to remove them and repeat linear regression analyses. Specifically I want to remove studentized residuals  larger than 3 and data points with cooks D > 4/n. How could I perform that in the sample data and do the same analysi swithout the influential points?

Sample data:

```
hsb2 <- read.csv("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/hsb2.csv")

lm1<-lm(write ~ read +ses + prog+race.f, data = hsb2)
```

Comment: I recommend that you use robust regression instead, e.g., function `lmrob` from package robustbase.

Comment: see `?influence.measures`

Comment: You can look at one example in the link below. It uses R to remove outliers based on cooks' distance. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164099/removing-outliers-based-on-cooks-distance-in-r-language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the weights of those points to zero, then `update` the model:

```
w <- abs(rstudent(lm1)) < 3 & abs(cooks.distance(lm1)) < 4/nrow(lm1$model)
lm2 <- update(lm1, weights=as.numeric(w))
```

This is probably a weak approach statistically, but at least the code isn't too hard...

Answer (score 0):

You could also remove the values with high leverage and large residuals

```
HighLeverage <- cooks.distance(lm1) > (4/nrow(hsb2))
LargeResiduals <- rstudent(lm1) > 3
hsb2 <- hsb2[!HighLeverage & !LargeResiduals,]
lm1<-lm(write ~ read +ses + prog+race.f, data = hsb2)
```